# NodeJS app not accessible in public DNS after creating systemd service

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, dns, systemd

I have created Ubuntu 18.04 instance in AWS. I have created a nodeapp in it and with npm start, site is available in public DNS with port 5000. But to keep it running forever, i created a systemd service, while checking the status everything runs perfect. But site is not available in public DNS. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Please share your systemd unit file.

Comment: Mohit, there was a mistake from my side. I was pointing to app.js instead of bin/www, now everything  works well. Thanks